# Telegram Bot Not Receiving Images for Image Saving Feature

Tags: python, async-await, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I need some help....

This time I am building a little telegram bot for my instagram sells...

I want to add a feature for saving image from bot to python.

Text messages is works normally, but...

When I try to send image for examle from my phone or web browser, my python server can not receives that image...

```
# if photo taken
if awaiting_photo and photo:
    if photo:
        photo_file = await context.bot.get_file(update.message.photo[-1].file_id)
    elif update.message.document:
        photo_file = await context.bot.get_file(update.message.document.file_id)
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text("Please send photo.")

    # Save photo
    photo_path = f"{temp_model_info['model_no']}.jpg"
    await photo_file.download_to_drive(custom_path=photo_path)

    # MODEL_DATA to json
    MODEL_DATA[temp_model_info['model_no']] = {
        "price": temp_model_info['price'],
        "info": "In stocks!!!",
        "image": photo_path
    }
    with open('model_data.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(MODEL_DATA, json_file, indent=4)

    awaiting_photo = False
    await update.message.reply_text(f"Model {temp_model_info['model_no']} succesfully added..")

    return
```

I tried several methods but still not working.

Can you guys help me please?

Thanks...

Comment: do you get error? show FULL error message in question (not in comments) as text (not image).

Comment: did you tried to use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables?

Comment: Yeah. I tried something to show with print. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with adding some more functions after I asked here guys. Thanks all...

And also, dont remember, you need to send your image as a folder for pc automation with bots...

```
async def handle_photo(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    global awaiting_photo, temp_model_info
    if awaiting_photo:
        photo = update.message.photo
        if photo:
            photo_file = await context.bot.get_file(update.message.photo[-1].file_id)
        elif update.message.document:
            photo_file = await context.bot.get_file(update.message.document.file_id)
        else:
            await update.message.reply_text("Send photo please...")
            photo_path = os.path.join(data_directory, f"{temp_model_info['model_no']}.jpg")
        await photo_file.download_to_drive(custom_path=photo_path)
            MODEL_DATA[temp_model_info['model_no']] = {
            "price": temp_model_info['price']+"TL",
            "info": "In stocks.",
            "image": photo_path
        }
        with open(model_data_path, 'w') as json_file:
            json.dump(MODEL_DATA, json_file, indent=4)

        awaiting_photo = False
        await update.message.reply_text(f"Model {temp_model_info['model_no']} added succesfuly.")
```

and adding this to main function...

```
application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.PHOTO, handle_photo))
```